# How to catch a "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect" exception

Tags: java, mysql, exception

To check what happens when the server is down or the network is not working I stopped Apache and MySQL services and ran my code.
I got following error:

> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

how can I catch this exception in code?

I've tried this:

```
public static Connection getCon(){
  Connection con=null;


  try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    con=DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/zomatocrm","root","");
  }

  catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    if(e.getCause() instanceof SQLException){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection refused!");
    }                   
  }
  return con;
}
```

And also this

```
 public static Connection getCon(){
   Connection con=null;

   try{
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
     con=DriverManager.getConnection(
         "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/zomatocrm","root","");
   }

   catch(Exception e){
     System.out.println(e.getMessage());
     if(e.getCause() instanceof ConnectException){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection refused!");
     }                   
   }
   return con;
 }
```

Also I've used the connection to do data exchange with my xampp localhost sever and then tried with stopping xamp and still getting the above exception.

How do I have my code catch the exception completely?

Comment: IN short suggest how can i check if the connection is good while my code is running!!!..

Comment: What do you expect? Your code *explicitly* prints the message, so you get the message. Also note that your method will simply return `null` when it fails, which will simply delay the problem and throw a `NullPointerException` later. What do you actually expect your code to do, when it can't connect to the DB?

Comment: i want a pop up when this exception is thrown...which is not happening!! the code is nt working as expected!!!...yes i want to kno when it cant connect to DB!!

Comment: @srijan: please go easy on the superfluous exclamation marks and full stops and learn to use full words. Why don't you simply show the popup on all `SQLExceptions`? Does it really matter *why* you failed to connect to the database? Also: what do you want to happen *after* you showed the message? There's still some code waiting for it's `Connection`.

Answer (score -2):

1. Don't check the cause, but the exception itself
2. Catch only the kind of exception you need to catch

With that in mind:

```
public static Connection getCon() {
    Connection con=null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/zomatocrm", "root", "");
    }
    catch (ConnectException e){
       System.out.println(e.getMessage());
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection refused!!!");
    }
    return con;
}
```

Comment: the code inside try also throws SQLException...how will keep track of that!!

Comment: **Actually** `ConnectException` is never thrown in that code! I suspect that a `SQLException` is thrown where the `ConnectException` is the *cause*!